# Sorting BigDecimal

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, java-7, bigdecimal

What is the problem with this BigDecimalSorting? The code takes in numbers as string and then converts it to BigDecimal and then sort and print the sorted BigDecimals.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
public static void main(String []argh){

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    String []s=new String[n];
    BigDecimal a[] = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        s[i]=sc.next();
        a[i] = new BigDecimal(s[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < n; j++){
            if(a[i].compareTo(a[j]) == -1){
                BigDecimal temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    //Output
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        s[i] = a[i].toString();
        System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Sample Input:
9
-100
50
0
56.6
90
0.12
.12
02.34
000.000

Expected Output:
90
56.6
50
02.34
0.12
.12
0
000.000
-100

Comment: what is your error? your expected input/output?

Comment: Please mention your problem or expected i/o

Comment: The method of working on this site is that *you* explain what the problem is, and then people can try to help you. If you don't know if there is a problem or what the problem is, you should first figure that out before posting a question on this site.

Comment: What is the problem here really? Are you facing any errors (if so, please paste stack trace too)

Comment: This is think problem is for 0.12 & .12.While initializing these numbers using BigDecimal,It consider both as 0.12.https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-bigdecimal

Answer (score 8):

You can use the comparator to sort the BigDecimal

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;

class Solution{

public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    String []s=new String[n+2];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        s[i]=sc.next();
    }
    sc.close();

    Arrays.sort(s, 0, n, new Comparator<Object>() {
        public int compare(Object a1, Object a2) {
            BigDecimal bigDec1 = new BigDecimal((String) a1);
            BigDecimal bigDec2 = new BigDecimal((String) a2);
            return bigDec2.compareTo(bigDec1);
        }
    });


    //Output
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why compare on Object and cast? Stick with String?

Comment: What is the diff between Arrays.sort(s, new Comparator<Object>() ...) and Arrays.sort(s, 0, n, new Comparator<Object>()...)? I am getting Null point exception in the first case.

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;
class Solution{

    public static void main(String []argh)
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String []s=new String[n+2];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            s[i]=sc.next();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            BigDecimal max=new BigDecimal(s[i]);
            int idx=i;
            for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                BigDecimal curr=new BigDecimal(s[j]);
                if(curr.compareTo(max)==1)
                {
                    max=curr;
                    idx=j;
                }
            }
            String temp=s[i];
            s[i]=s[idx];
            s[idx]=temp;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(s[i]);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: An explanation of _why_ this is a valid solution when compared to the poster's code would be very appropriate. For bonus points, a comparison to the other answers (which were posted several months before you showed up) and why yours is either better or at least different (and worthy of having been posted well after these others) would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're throwing an NPE because you're trying to access a null array.

```
    BigDecimal a[] = null;  // <---- null array

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s[i] = sc.next();
        a[i] = new BigDecimal(s[i]); // <---- accessing null array a
    }
```

Try initializing your array with the n length used on input

```
    BigDecimal a[] = new BigDecimal[n];
```

**Edit**

in response to Mariano's answer, your

```
    if (a[i].compareTo(a[j]) == -1)
```

is correct, as is. See [BigDecimal javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal))

> Returns: 
>   -1, 0, or 1 as this BigDecimal is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than val.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors in your code.

First you are not initializing the **a** array, `BigDecimal a[] = null` should be replaced by `BigDecimal a[] = new BigDecimal[n]` to avoid the NullPointerException.

Finally you are implementing the sort algorithm wrong, you should replace the inner `for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)` with `for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)`

Here is how your code should look like:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(final String[] argh) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String[] s = new String[n];
        BigDecimal a[] = new BigDecimal[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            s[i] = sc.next();
            a[i] = new BigDecimal(s[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (a[i].compareTo(a[j]) == -1) {
                    BigDecimal temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[i];
                    a[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        // Output
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            s[i] = a[i].toString();
            System.out.println(s[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Collections.sort()` provides a simpler version of Sahil's answer:

```
List<BigDecimal> values = Arrays.asList(new BigDecimal[] {
  new BigDecimal("1.2"),
  new BigDecimal("1.1"),
  new BigDecimal("9.2"),
  new BigDecimal("4.2"),
});

// Sort from low to high
Collections.sort(values);    

for (var value : values) {
  System.out.println(value);
}
```